# Is there a fast way to draw text in WPF

Tags: wpf

I need to display a lot of text in my WPF window.

I am using DrawingContext.DrawText but it is too slow.

I tried DrawingContext.DrawGlyph. The call itself is faster but if you count the glyph creation, it is about the same time.

Is there a way to speed things up even it means loosing text quality?

Comment: more explanation would go a long way.  how slow is "too slow"?

Comment: probable duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067750/why-is-wpfs-drawingcontext-drawtext-so-expensive

Comment: Not duplicate: the other question did not get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with TextBlock controls ? I put them on a Canvas, and for me it turned out to be faster than solutions involving FormattedText or DrawingContext.DrawGlyphRun().