# create custom control which include a text and a image

Tags: wpf

I want to show a lot of (hundreds of or more) controls in a window, the control include a text and a image and have 4 different appearances (different text color and image), when user click the control, its appearance will switch among the 4.

In order to improve performance, I want to create a custom control and try to choose a good lightweight base class for it, after googling, seems UIElement is the most lightweight, which involving call DrawText and DrawImage on DrawingContext object, however, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067750/why-is-wpfs-drawingcontext-drawtext-so-expensive) indicate the DrawText is expensive.

Another choise is control such as ContentControl, TextBlock or Button, but they are more heavy than UIElement, does anybody have any advice? many thanks.

Comment: Start with a DataTemplate: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: I'd just go with textblock for the text. Can the image be a shape instead?

Comment: @Andy the image is loaded from png file.